# Encryption of an AES Key with forge library React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, encryption

I'm now working on the encryption/decryption task, and I'm facing some issues.
I'm getting the public RSA key from the Java based server. The encryption type should be:
RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding.
To encrypt the value, I used the below code (that you can also find here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge#rsa) :

```
const getPEMPublicKey = (publicKey) => {
  const pubKeyArr = publicKey.match(/.{1,64}/g)
  return '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n' + join(pubKeyArr, "\n") + '\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
}

const encryptAESKey = (AESKey, publicKey) => {
  // encrypt data with a public key using RSAES-OAEP/SHA-256/MGF1-SHA-1
  // compatible with Java's RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding
  const publicKeyPem = forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(getPEMPublicKey(publicKey));
  const rsaEncryptedAesKey = publicKeyPem.encrypt(forge.util.encodeUtf8(AESKey), 'RSA-OAEP', {
    md: forge.md.sha256.create(),
    mgf1: {
      md: forge.md.sha1.create()
    }
  });
  return rsaEncryptedAesKey
}
```

the rsaEncryptedKey is not correct, this is the weird data I get:

```
   1]*Q^?o>Ãn±Ýut¼dªjfôUc$ÃÆ|&¾ZTW2
    ×é_Í>ú;î¥äÊæ[jU.<¡X3ßöAsÑg½LD¥º&ÍaÎòuHÍGHóº@|YÀWÇöõ<ðªK Î¶uäÚ³©Ëò­øUj·töTa:/Çý/L4x]äiXéqÅAFÓÌKwL B3$aÍB>ÕwÉÿ<[ò
    x"ÞåXàh\÷p;w<§÷RyÈL¬ð5EÁ9¿´,_Ö½<Áy×ÇÁÖ6
```

I get the public key from the backend in base 64, example:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAm+m0v4JKo5lb6f6pypFG/xS4wzJEJ80m3SbXs7sTQtvgblrczyjKYm5oYOVG1onWJ8XmbEdDts/sIYBArc37xLtaOgYr480YU8aqj026qc2mblpTLkGJiye0z0LmpsoQXvqZ49UD+ZHG7PetkLgIW5H+ffw2vW4fdBi9fZU6jJ9z8dkv0PLtAZ2LEuVLAqEE6rHzmEc5EmfMy70/FCRZZShS2Yq76/qGgTzlVpzV4r4d0D83Zz+ZWIL1MISGk8x86moYzM2w+8o2N0V0cDayCQKnoEiNxSKXw3+uIyoqjR7gcdlqgWfl/Wb8G5W8TemnFkOMTuUq9tZlgoadyqxjtQIDAQAB
```

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas? I cannot find a lot of information online.

Comment: Looks to me like you simply need to base64-encode the result.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I tried with base64 library and also with Buffer.from(rsaEncryptedKey).toString('base64'). but in those cases, I get an error in BE: the Data must not be longer than 256 bytes. Note that if I encode the values with an online tool, it gets decoded correctly in the backend